# How to preserve spacing before + operator in `multlined` environment?

Tags: equations, mathtools, multline

How to keep the space before `+` operator?

[image]

Here there is the code to generate the example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{multlined}
    a = b + c
  \end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{multlined}
    a = b + \\ + c
  \end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `{}` after the `+`: `a = b +{} \\ + c`

Comment: @gernot, do you intend to write answer? or we close the question as solved by comment?

Comment: @Zarko I've found a duplicate, so let's close it.

Comment: I spent quite a lot of time trying to find the answer on my question. Maybe then it would be useful to make the formulation of the original question more general?